# Is there a way to plug in a node generated texture map in a modifier?

Tags: texturing, modifiers, node-editor

I have found in my previous research that there is quite a divide between node based textures/images and Image textures in the properties panel.
Is there any way to plug in a node tree as texture into a modifier? For example to use a node based texture for a displacement modifier. I know there is a node to displace things in the render without the modifier. But I would like the displacement to be actual geometry so it can be printed.
The only way I see so far is to bake out the generated texture as an image and then to load the image in as a texture in the modifier.
It would be very nice if there was a way to have them linked directly so I can adjust the nodes on the fly while seeing the result live.
Is that possible?

Comment: Unfortunately the Displacement Modifier doesn't accept procedurally generated textures from shader node graphs - It only accepts the built-in "noises" as well as bitmap image textures. If you want to use your custom texture as the basis for a Displacement Modifier, then yes, you must bake it.

Comment: How inconvenient. Well thank you for your quick answer.